# Why was my legacy question closed and locked?

Tags: support, specific-question

[Are there any studies on the Efficiency/Effectiveness of Agile vs Waterfall](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/125429/26304)

I asked this question 6 years ago and It finally got some good information then the answer was deleted and the post locked by a mod.  There was no reason given in comments.  I can see closing it but the locking seems overkill.

Comment: full content of deleted answer for those with <10K rep: "Here are a couple links that may be of use:

[Ambysoft’s 2013 Project Success Rates Survey](http://www.ambysoft.com/surveys/success2013.html)

[2015 CHAOS report from the Standish Group](https://www.infoq.com/articles/standish-chaos-2015)"

Comment: Sure you understand what the lock means? It prevents your question from being deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is now off-topic, per the Help Center. The locking makes it much more clear that the question and others like it no longer fit the rules of the site. However, there was good and valuable content and locking preserves that. The alternative is deletion.

Comment: I get that it was off topic.  but why not just close it and leave it unlocked?

Comment: I seem to remember having seen the legacy content banner before

Comment: @Chad Because that gives the wrong impression to users. The lock makes it clear that questions like this don't belong, but there's already useful content and just destroying it would be bad for the greater community.